# How to return promise

Tags: javascript

I have not been able to get my wits around promises.

I have this function:

```
response(theResponse) {
    return theResponse.json();
}
```

`theReponse.json()` is code which returns a promise.

This works, and returns a promise which resolves to an array.

However, I need to modify this so I can get access to the array, and then process the array, and then return it in a promise.

How do I do that?

Comment: Your argument is the same name as the function. That no look good to me.

Comment: I don't see any promises in your question. Care to explain?

Comment: `return theResponse.json().then(arr => ...);`

Comment: Post Edited to show the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if that `json()` method returns promise then you can use `then()`

```
response(theResponse) {
    return theResponse.json().then(function(arr) {
      //do something with arr 
      return arr;
    }); // then() returns new promise so it can be chained
}
```

Check "promise chaining" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining).

Answer (score 1):

You can compose promise pipelines using [`Promise#then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

```
function response(theResponse) {
  return theResponse.json().then(function(array) {
    // process array
    return array;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add onto the other answers, you should always catch your promises so that errors don't get "swallowed".

```
response(theResponse) {
    return theResponse
             .json()
             .then(arr => arr)   // handle resolve
             .catch(err => err); // handle reject
}
```